# How can I show that $\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x}{n^2+x^2}\right|\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ for any $x\in{\bf R}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Show that
>   $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x}{n^2+x^2}\right|\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$$

---

It is true for $x=0$. But I don't see how it is true for any $x\in{\bf R}$. The identity $\frac{\pi}{2}=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$ may help, I think. But I don't know how to go on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider the function $f(y) = \dfrac1{y^2+x^2}$. This is a monotonically decreasing function for $y>0$. Hence, we have
$$\dfrac1{n^2+x^2} < \int_{n-1}^{n} \dfrac{dy}{y^2+x^2}$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{n^2+x^2} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{n-1}^{n} \dfrac{dy}{y^2+x^2} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{dy}{y^2+x^2} = \dfrac{\pi}{2x}$$

Comment: Beautiful answer. +1

Comment: The hunter captures his prey...

Comment: $a_n<b_n$ implies $\lim a_n\leq \lim b_n$ but not necessarily $\lim a_n<\lim b_n$.

Comment: @Jack  If $a_n<b_n$ then $\sum a_n<\sum b_n$.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: Fair enough. I find that I just made a silly comment. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

You can rewrite the sum to
$$
\frac {1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(\frac n x)^2+1}
$$
Because $f(n)=\frac1{n^2+1}$ is strictly decreasing for positive (reals) $n$, we know that 
\begin{align}
\frac 1x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(\frac nx)^2+1}&\leq \frac 1x\int_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(\frac nx)^2+1} dn\\
&=\frac 1x \left(x \frac \pi 2\right)=\frac \pi 2
\end{align}
For the integral, i used the substitution $m=\frac nx$, and because $dm=\frac 1x dn$, we get the factor $x$ in the result.

Answer (score 6):

By showing that the sum is exactly

$$\frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname*{coth}{(\pi x)} - \frac1{2 x}$$

This may be done via, e.g., the residue theorem.  Note that the expression is bounded from above by $\pi/2$ as $x \to \infty$

Comment: This is correct, but since this question is tagged [tag:real-analysis], I wonder if the OP will find it useful.

Comment: @robjohn It think it's a nice supplement to the other answers, at least.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x}{n^2+x^2}\right| < \int_0^\infty{\frac{x}{n^2+x^2}dn}$$ for any $x\in{\Bbb R}$

Evaluating the integral we get $$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty{\frac{x}{n^2+x^2}dn} &= tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{n}{x}\bigg)\bigg|_0^\infty \\
&= \lim_{t\to\infty} tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{t}{x}\bigg) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}$$

Therefore $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x}{n^2+x^2}\right| < \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: You say $$\left| \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{n^2+x^2} \right| < \int_0^\infty \frac{x}{n^2+x^2}dx \tag{1}$$ Are you claiming $\frac{x}{n^2+x^2}$ is decreasing for all $x>0$? How can you show that? Or if not, how do you justify (1)?

Comment: @EricAuld sry I meant $$\int_0^\infty{\frac{x}{n^2+x^2}dn}$$, not $$\int_0^\infty{\frac{x}{n^2+x^2}dx}$$

Comment: I claim this because the sigma is adding the values of the funcion at positive integer points, while the integral is summing up all of the values of the function at all points from $[0, \infty)$

Comment: I agree that is what is going on, but that does not establish the inequality. You have to show the function is decreasing to compare with an integral. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Comment: because x is just a constant, the integral is decreasing because the denominator is increasing as n gets larger and larger. It's always positive as well, and it's continuous on the interval from $(0, \infty)$

Comment: Got it, thanks.