# Is it true that $\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{n^2+x^2}\right|<\frac{\pi}{2}$ for any $x\in \Bbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is a question closely related to this one:

[How can I show that $\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x}{n^2+x^2}\right|\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ for any $x\in{\Bbb R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/611186/9464)

Here is my **question**:

> Is the strict inequality also true?

---

Several answers to the question I just quoted use the following argument, which is wrong:

> $a_n<b_n$ for all $n$ implies that $\lim a_n<\lim b_n$.

While we have $\lim a_n\leq\lim b_n$ provided that $a_n<b_n$ for all $n$, the strict inequality is not necessarily true. For example:
$$
a_n=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{n},\ \ b_n=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{2n}. 
$$

But I have no idea how to approach the question above.

Comment: The inequality is strict in the accepted answer in the question you mentioned. So that clearly means the sum can never be $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Grumpy Parsnip, I find that I just made a silly comment to the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/611193/9464) of the quoted [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/611186/9464).

It is not true that $a_n<b_n$ implies $\lim_n a_n<\lim b_n$. It is also not true that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^Na_n<\sum_{n=1}^Nb_n
$$
implies 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n.
$$
However, it is *true* that
$$
a_n<b_n
$$
implies
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n.
$$

Therefore, according to the accepted [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/611193/9464), the strict inequality is obtained.

Answer (score 0):

From complex analysis, 
$$\mathrm{coth} (z) = \frac 1 z +  2z \left( \frac{1}{z^2  + (\pi)^2 }+\frac{1}{z^2  + (2\pi)^2 }+\frac{1}{z^2  + (3\pi)^2 }+\dots \right)$$
By changing  $z \to z \pi  $
$$\coth\left( z\pi \right) = \frac{1}{z\pi} + \frac{2z}{\pi} \left( \frac 1{z^2 + 1^2} + \frac 1{z^2 + 2^2} +\frac 1{z^2 + 3^2} +\dots\right)$$
We just need to check if has real roots.
$$\coth(z\pi) - \frac 1 {z\pi} = 1$$
I suppose the strict [inequality is true](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20z-%3Einfinity%20coth%28pi%20z%29%20-%201/%28z%20pi%29). since the graph is like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%20coth%28pi%20z%29%20-%201/%28z%20pi%29%20from%20z=-5%20to%205).

Answer (score 0):

In the same spirit as Santosh Linkha's answer, you could have identified that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{n^2+x^2}=\frac{\pi  x \coth (\pi  x)-1}{2 x}$$ and that the function represented by the rhs has an asymptotic value of $\frac{\pi^{-}}{2}$.